Javascript does not execute code right after an awaited call immediately (it does other stuff in between) after the async function returned
I'll begin by showing what should be the expected output, both from a sensible view point and because it's what happens if the functions weren't async.
Edit: It is also what would happen if foo and bar received "done" callbacks instead of Promise.then callbacks.
about to resolve
about to return from foo
code right after awaited return from foo
about to return from bar
code right after awaited return from bar

But between returning from a function and executing the next line of code in the caller, Javascript is interleaving other code, resulting in the following:
about to resolve
about to return from foo
about to return from bar
code right after awaited return from foo
code right after awaited return from bar

I wonder if there's a way to prevent it. I need the next line of code in the caller to be executed right after the async function returns.
That's the output of the following code:


async function caller(cb) {
    await cb();
    console.log(`code right after awaited return from ${ cb.name }`);
}

const { promise, resolve } = Promise.withResolvers();

async function foo() {
    await promise;
    console.log('about to return from foo');
}

async function bar() {
    await promise;
    console.log('about to return from bar');
}

caller(foo);
caller(bar);

console.log('about to resolve');
resolve();




To follow up on my general answer to the question as written: why do you care about this? There’s probably a solution to the motivating problem.

Sorry, I think discussing my motivating example would distract from solving this. and why do you care about it anyway?

As I mentioned in my answer, there is no way to solve this, so I care about the motivating problem in order to solve it instead.

Don't worry about that, I will solve the motivating problem somehow. But I'd prefer to solve it with awaits-asyncs that I could follow sensibly. Perhaps a class extending Promise is a promising solution ha!

If the deepest awaited promise can be controlled, then it can be changed by a custom subclass of Promise that saves the prior then and invokes handlers in order, after previous handlers were completed.
class SafePromise extends Promise {
    prior = Promise.resolve();

    then(onfulfilled, onrejected) {
        const prior = this.prior;
        const { promise, resolve } = Promise.withResolvers();
        this.prior = promise;
        return super.then(
            wrap(onfulfilled),
            wrap(onrejected)
        );

        function wrap(handler) {
            return async (_) => {
                await prior;
                try {
                    return await handler?.(_);
                } finally {
                    resolve();
                }
            };
        }
    }
}

But if the deepest promise is irremediably a native promise, then there really is no way to control the order of execution of await chains because the promise instance can't be changed to another promise class other than awaiting it, at which point the damage is already done because the then callback invocation is scheduled in a microtask.
Javascript is also obtuse in adopting subclasses of Promise for async functions that await another subclass, it always just creates a native promise. The code to get back to awaiters might be something like this:
function then() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        queueMicrotask(() => {
            promise.then(resolve, reject);
        });
    });
}

I can't think of a reason why it was designed this way, it doesn't resemble the ubiquitous call stack, which is the order the code executed and awaits were encountered in the first place. So the order up the chain is different from the order down the chain, it's not intuitive, and it's also inconsistent with "done" callbacks which is what promises aimed to substitute.
In the second case, use a sync "done" callback that can be executed at the end of the async function simulating it returning as soon as possible.
If an api that works with both cases is required, the awaited function must return a promise that never resolves when using the callback and return normally when not. Code in the callback and after await is repeated though.
async function awaited(doneCallback) {
    // ...
    const result = await somePromise;
    if (doneCallback) {
        doneCallback(result); // simulate synchronous return
        return new Promise(() => {}); // and never resolve.
    }
    // otherwise return as expected of an await for this function.
    return result;
}


You would need to fundamentally change the behavior of Promises. If you were to change your code to use then instead of async/await this could work:


class DepthFirstPromise {
    constructor(executor) {
        this.handlers = [];
        this.resolvedValue = null;
        this.isResolved = false;

        if (executor) {
            executor(this.resolve.bind(this));
        }
    }

    resolve(value) {
        if (this.isResolved) return;
        this.isResolved = true;
        this.resolvedValue = value;

        // Execute handlers in depth-first fashion
        while (this.handlers.length) {
            const handler = this.handlers.shift();
            handler(value);
        }
    }

    then(onFulfilled) {
        const nextPromise = new DepthFirstPromise();

        const wrapper = (value) => {
            try {
                const result = onFulfilled(value);
                if (result && typeof result.then === 'function') {
                    result.then(nextPromise.resolve.bind(nextPromise));
                } else {
                    nextPromise.resolve(result);
                }
            } catch (err) {
                nextPromise.resolve(Promise.reject(err));
            }
        };

        if (this.isResolved) {
            wrapper(this.resolvedValue);
        } else {
            this.handlers.push(wrapper);
        }

        return nextPromise;
    }

    static withResolvers() {
        const dfPromise = new DepthFirstPromise();
        return {
            promise: dfPromise,
            resolve: dfPromise.resolve.bind(dfPromise),
        };
    }
}

// Use the DepthFirstPromise
const { promise, resolve } = DepthFirstPromise.withResolvers();

function foo() {
    return promise.then(() => console.log("about to return from foo"));
}

function bar() {
    return promise.then(() => console.log("about to return from bar"));
}

function caller(cb) {
    return cb().then(() =>
        console.log(`code right after awaited return from ${cb.name}`)
    );
}

caller(foo);
caller(bar);

console.log("about to resolve");
resolve();



However, async/await are tightly coupled to the Promise type, so this won't work using async/await. I think creating a Promise-like object like this would only lead to confusion and future bugs. You're probably better off thinking about why you need your caller function to behave the way you're describing, and make that an explicit part of your code's APIs and patterns.

I'll consider this if it works later with more time, because it looks overly complicated. Thanks.

I see, is a matter of promises not being implemented correctly then. Would you happen to know why aren't they implemented this way? This would be consistent with sync functions and with "done" callbacks (which is what you'd expect from .then)

there might be a way to improve on this code with DepthFirstPromise extending Promise so that it also works with async-await, since the way Symbol.species works, it would maintain the same specialized class.

@MiguelLeon: even if you extend the Promise type, async/await always queues the await continuation as a microtask. As for "why," I think it simply stemmed from the queue structure used by JavaScript's event loop. This was probably the simplest way to implement async/await. C# took a more flexible approach with TaskSchedulers, allowing for different behavior for different purposes, but that created its own headaches (e.g. code that works in a console app and deadlocks in a GUI). It's all about tradeoffs.

Thank you very much for your insights and references. That it "was probably the simplest way" is a valid reason, and one that I prefer to "any other way is wrong" which is what @Ry- suggested. Even if it came with it's own headeaches, your comparison with C# helps demonstrates that other approaches are valid as well.

I'll try and see if an implementation of a depth first promise that extends Promise, is possible somehow. Thanks for the idea.


I wonder if there's a way to prevent it.

No, not in portable JavaScript. Using await is explicitly opting into yielding control and being resumed whenever the promise decides, necessarily involving a microtask in a microtask queue that you don’t locally control.
Even in the cases when you can rely on a particular ordering of microtasks, doing so is a code smell. You should wait for any operations you depend on explicitly.

what you say doesn't make sense as a response, because I'm not talking about the orders for the awaits, I'm talking about the order of the code that follows, after the awaiting is fulfilled which simply put, should continue after the return as in any normal call.

to follow up on this, the whole purpose of the async-await was to remove the callback hell, but if foo and bar received callbacks themselves in order to continue, this would work as expected. Meaning that callbacks and promises work in different ways defeating the purpose in the first place.

@MiguelLeon: I didn’t misunderstand that. You used an async function, not callbacks. Maybe there’s more purpose to async functions than working exactly like callbacks in all situations?

Notably, since async functions run to their first await when called, they can’t return without a microtask, or they’d end up “calling their callback” synchronously, which was a common mistake when using callbacks (creating stack overflows and surprising execution order that wouldn’t otherwise have existed). (Same for returning resolved promises synchronously.) If you’ve ever seen process.nextTick(callback) in Node, that bug is often why.

Please, tell me more about the reasoning, you're talking about some scenarios but I don't know if they apply. What's wrong in behaving the same as a "done" callback? or about calling it synchronously? although I maybe it's still possible to order them with microtasks. What's that about process.nextTick?. I appreciate where you're going, I'd like to know more

you could do
caller(foo).then(()=>{caller(bar)});

ofcourse the two caller calls will not be ran concurrently but sequentially (meaning caller(bar) will wait for caller(foo) to finish), but it sounds to me like that's what you want.
EDIT: also the next line of code is in fact being called immediately after the async function returns, however the other async caller function is running concurrently in your code, so they're not waiting for each other, which they are in the code i posted here, as "then" waits for the promise of the async function to resolve.
this would practically be pretty much the same as this:
(async ()=>{ 
    await caller(foo);
    await caller(bar)
})()

EDIT: is this what you want, based on discussion below? (removed the code that was not what you wanted)
async function caller(cb) {
    await cb();
    console.log(`code right after awaited return from ${ cb.name }`);
    (async ()=>{
        //rest of caller code, there is no awaiting this, it will run however long it takes.
    })();
}

const { promise, resolve } = Promise.withResolvers();

async function foo() {
    await promise;
   console.log('about to return from foo');
}

async function bar() {
    await promise;
    console.log('about to return from bar');
}
(async ()=>{
    await caller(foo); // will wait until the point cb()/foo() has finished, it will not wait for the rest of the caller code.
    await caller(bar); // same as above
    //...etc.
})();
console.log('about to resolve');
resolve();


Using .then instead of await, works the same. Could you show a working example?

I understand now, you mean to make the calls wait on each other. That's not desired though. Thanks.

if that's not what is desired, then what you got is what you need, there is nothing weird going on with your code. caller(foo) and caller(bar) are running simultaneously, so ofcourse you will not get the order that you posted as expected. cause that expectation comes about when caller(foo) runs and finishes and then caller(bar) runs (and finishes)

No, you're proposing to wait for the whole execution of caller(foo) before the whole execution of caller(bar). If you think about it, you don't need the that. I'm talking about continued execution when possible, i.e. when an await is resolved, no need to interleave execution after that point if there isn't another await

@MiguelLeon well you don't have to call await on caller(bar) no, but that's not what's happening in my first example, with .then either, the second example you just take the await away before caller(bar), although the await there doesn't make a difference if you don't have more code in that anonymous async function. when an await is resolved the whole function you are awaiting is resolved, that is the whole point of await.

I don't understand, but like I explained, if you're await complete execution of caller(foo) before even starting caller(bar), then that's not desired, caller(foo) might never even finish. What's desired is that the caller of foo continues its execution after awaiting foo, before any other code anywhere else is executed. Why? because it is the  caller of foo and foo is done.
I hope this explanation is clearer, if this is also what you're trying to achieve, please help me understand you with a complete example.

@MiguelLeon it's not much clearer to be honest, but i'll try my best. the caller of foo is the caller function, this caller might never finish, and presumably in the real scenario there is code in caller before cb is being called as well as after but you want in the case of foo the code up until cb (foo in this case) to be executed before anything else (like for example caller(bar)) is being executed? i have to go to bed now, so i will add a possibly not well enough thought through answer in my post above.

@MiguelLeon i added another option, in case you want this to happen for anything called with caller, so also caller(bar) see the last block of code.

No. Like I said before, no need to await the whole execution of caller(foo) before even invoking caller(bar), because foo might not even finish. Try to picture it with "done" callbacks in the following example https://runjs.co/s/4eYGtv019

@MiguelLeon my last piece of code is what i think you want to do. it executes caller up until and including cb (foo/bar) then the function returns, the await caller(foo) is done, while the rest of the caller function continues running asynchronously, there is no waiting for the rest of the code to finish, it might never finish like you said, but the code will call caller(bar) and once bar, as cb has finished executing, the etc. code will be called if any, while also the rest of caller code will be running for caller(bar) simultaneously there is no waiting for that to finish..

The code you propose does not work in the way you're describing it. caller(bar) is waiting the whole of caller(foo) to complete in order to start. Try changing await promise in foo by await new Promise(), a promise that's never resolved, and you'll realize.

@MiguelLeon what is the code that you do not want to wait for? is it cb() (so foo) or is it the code in caller that follows the call to foo? cause if you don't want to wait for foo in caller, just remove the await in front of it in your own code.

any await caller(foo) or caller(foo).then(...) would await complete execution of caller(foo) before continuing. This is not desired and I'm sorry, but continuing to discuss about it, distracts from the point of the post which is the order of execution of the code after calls to foo and bar.

@MiguelLeon you are absolutely completely unclear about what you want to accomplish, perhaps you could try to convey it in your native tongue, in the code in my post await caller(foo) doesn't wait for the complete execution of caller foo, well technically, but it doesn't wait for the code in that anonymous async function. my understanding was that you wanted to execute everything in caller up and including the call to cb and then not wait for the rest that comes after that. so it puts that in a seperate async call. if you do not want to wait for the cb call just remove the await in front of it

await caller(foo) does wait for its complete execution before continuing, contrary to what you describe. I don't know how else to explain it to you, I even told you what lines to change in order to see it break. Please don't insist on this anymore. The question isn't even about this. It's about how to execute the code after foo and bar's invokation, immediately after they finish without interleaving other code. Don't force the desired output through another code logic, otherwise you might as well just put 5 console.log in the order you desire.

what do you mean by "without interleaving other code" any code put either in cb().then(()=>{\code here}) will be executed immediately after cb finishes, if you await cb anything after that line will be executed immediately after cb finishes. so the question is what do you mean by "without interleaving other code"? cause that sounds like you just want it synchronous which you accomplish with await, but you say you don't want that. the code isn't interleaving anything, the console.logs are appearing in a different order, because multiple functions are running simultaneously, asynchronously

No. Again you're describing something that does not happen. The code in the cb().then(...) does not execute immediately after cb finishes and this is exactly the point of the question, because you'd expect the then callback to happen right after cb finishes, but it does not. Refer to the actual question with the expected and actual output. You saying this is not clear to you, is hard to believe, since it's even in the title of the question.

@MiguelLeon you completely misunderstand what asynchronous execution is. if you don't await the first async call before calling the second one they will both run at the same time. the output will be mixed up exactly as expected. "then" will definitely be called immediately after the promise is resolved, aka when the async function returns. besides all the examples that i have given you the past few days give exactly the output that you say you want / are expecting. but you keep saying you want them running at the same time, but then you complain about the output that goes along with that.

At this point I think you're just trolling. Sure, whatever you say, I don't understand what asynchronous execution is, and whatever you proposed is the absolute only way to achieve the desired goal. I'm disengaging now ✌️.

@MiguelLeon trolling? i'm sorry for taking my time trying to understand you and help you, it's unfortunate that it hasn't worked out. i don't think anyone else would've tried so much with you.

I can see why you might think you're helping just for trying. But you've constantly described things that're not in the way you describe them, and suggested things that change the logic of the example program. I actually thought I was the one helping you gain a broader view of the async code and how it's feasible for it to behave in a different way.

In any case, the purpose of these kind of questions is to discover if there's a trick or api I'm missing, or to discover an approach or an idea through which I can obtain the desired goal. It's not, to be constantly hammered by someone saying "it's not possible", or "don't expect that", or "change your logic", etc. Also, don't worry about the solution anymore, I though of something that works, I'll post it soon.


Since caller() is an async function and await has not been used on it, it will execute in an async manner.

This means that when caller() is invoked, it begins execution and immediately returns a Promise.
The code will continue to the next line without waiting for it to complete its execution.
The function itself will complete by returning a promise, not the actual results of its execution.



If the order of execution matters (i.e., you want to ensure one async operation completes before starting another OR execute in a sync manner), you need to use await or chain the function call with .then(). Using either of these will ensure that the promise returned by the async function is resolved before moving on to the next line of code.
// Making sure that caller(boo) only begins after caller(foo) has been completed
(async () => {
    await caller(foo);
    await caller(bar);
})()

OR
    caller(foo).then(() => caller(bar))


I don't understand what you say, could you show an example that works as expected?

@MiguelLeon I think one of the answers above is correct.

Correct about what? and why do you think that?
